# Textbox allows only alphanumeric and also allow leftarrow(<-)

Tags: jquery

**Requirement:** Textbox should allow only alphanumeric.

**My Problem:** 
My code is allowing only alphanumeric. But problem is  leftarrow(<-) is not working in google cromo and IE. Its working in mozilla firefox. For enter the backward text, its not allowing leftarrow(<-) key. How can i resolve it.

**code:**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.textId, new
{
   onkeyup = "this.value=this.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g,'');"
})
```